# C++ template return types

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 template classes, Vector3 and Matrix4x4. Vector3 is explicitly instantiated as `float`, `double` and `int`, whereas Matrix4x4 is explicitly instantiated as just `float` and `double`.

I'm thinking about the return type a user would expect when multiplying them with different types. The internal multiplication will happen such that non-matching types will promote one to the other, but I'm not sure what type to return e.g.

```
Vector3i vec3i(1, 2, 3);

Matrix4x4f mat4f; //Automatically set to identity

auto result = vec3i * mat4f;
auto result2 = mat4f * vec3i;
```

In both cases I think that result and result2 should both be vec3f, just as if I were to multiply an int with a `float`. I guess I'm just wondering if this is in line with common practice, or if not then if, instead of multiplying different types, I should be doing something like explicitly casting one to the other with `static_cast` and `casting operators`?

Comment: how do you intend to multiply a 3d vector by a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: @dwcanillas: He just said it -- "non-matching types will promote one to the other", just like "int and float".

Comment: @KerrekSB im not talking about types. im talking about mathematically, how do you multiply those two? its not possible.

Comment: @dwcanillas: you just extend the vector or the matrix with zeroes as necessary.

Comment: At the moment I am performing a multiplication with the upper-left 3x3 submatrix, however I suppose this could be ambiguous as the user may think it would perform a multiplication with a 4x3 submatrix. For the purposes of the question, let's ignore that - what type would you expect it to return?

Comment: @Rajveer: You're asking for design-level *advice*, without even specifying what you're using this for. As I see it that makes it off-topic. But just be aware that instead of hardcoding a `float` return type you can very easily infer it (if you go for that) via e.g. `declype( T()*U() )` where `T` and `U` are the two numeric types in question.

Comment: Yeah you're right - this will be used in a 3d math library for a game engine, for example if we have a set of integer coordinates that need transforming by a matrix. I had planned on using that decltype statement to return a promoted type in case of differing types (e.g. result/result2 = vec3f in the example above) and then a user could cast the returned type back if they wanted (e.g. back to a vec3i above), but I guess I wanted advice as to whether this is the "right" approach, or if I should perform the multiplication with the same types and make the user cast _before_ multiplication too?